# Jquery Relace Part of String in Any Class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reset a class for any links that have been previously selected by removing the end of a class name.

When the link is clicked on the class is appended with "_selected" so that the image remains highlighted. When another link is clicked on, I am trying to remove "_selected" from any link that may have been selected previously (many rollovers on the page).

Seems like the following should work:

$('a').attr('class').replace(/_selected/g, '');

Doesn't this look for all links with classes and replace instances of "_selected" with nothing?

Is there a better way to look at this? New to jQuery... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put more than one classes in an element, like:

```
<a class="someClass selected" />
```

So, with jQuery:

```
$("a.selected").removeClass("selected");
```

and of course previously you have added it with

```
$("your-selector").addClass("selected");
```

And you need to define it, of course

```
<style>
 A.selected {
     /*your styles here*/
 }
</style>
```

Not exactly what you want, but I think it is what you need :)

In fact, what you want is:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class").replace(/_selected/g,""));
});
```

Comment: The multiple classes option worked well enough for this situation. Didn't even occur to me. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

$('a').attr('class') will return the 'class' string for each jQuery 'a' elements and not the element itself...

I think you should do something like that :

$('a').each(function(){

$(this).attr('class', $(this).attr('class').replace(/_selected/g, ''));

});